# How to hide a checkboxlist based on a dropdown selection using JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, checkboxlist

I have a form with a dropdownlist. Based on the selected item in the dropdown respective chekbox list appears and other checkboxlist disappears. How can you accomplish this using JQuery?

Comment: Please show us what you've already done. Then we can help from there.

Comment: you mean hide (remove) or disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Javascript that you should be able to easily adapt to your specific elements:

```
$('#dropdownlist').on('change', function () { 
    if ($(this).val()) {
        if($(this).val() === "some value") {
            $('#somecheckboxgroup').show();
            $('#someothercheckboxgroup').hide();
        }
        else if($(this).val() === "some other value") {
            $('#somecheckboxgroup').hide();
            $('#someothercheckboxgroup').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Essentially, you just want to run a function every time the dropdownlist changes, and in it, check the currently selected value and then run your desired code based on the observed value.

Comment: Thanks for the edit -- don't know how I missed the closing quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really basic example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/G8z3r/
The code can be shortened up just by using different selectors, id's and classes but I wanted to give you a basic idea on how this works.

```
$('select[name="showbox"]').change(function() {
    if('foo' == $(this).val() ) {
        $('div').hide(); // make sure all divs are hidden
        $('#checkboxA').show(); // show the right one
    } else if ('bar' == $(this).val() ) {
        $('div').hide(); // make sure all divs are hidden
        $('#checkboxB').show(); // show the right one
    } else if ('both' == $(this).val() ) {
        $('div').show(); // sow all divs
    } else {
        $('div').hide();
    }
});
```